# "from ten days ahead" in this context

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs

> You should start the rehearsal **from ten days ahead** of the *play.*
>
> You should turn the indicators on **from one mile ahead** of the hospital.

Is the sentence pattern **from ahead of** valid in these sentences?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No - when speaking about time and dates, "*from*" usually means "any time after", for example:

> You can arrive from 1pm.

(this means you can arrive any time after 1pm)

If you actually mean to say that they should have *exactly* 10 days rehearsal time then you should simply say:

> You should start rehearsals ten days ahead of the play.

Or, if you are saying that 10 days is the *minimum* rehearsal time, you should say:

> You should start rehearsals *at least* ten days ahead of the play.

---

With your second question about mileage, you *can* say "from [x] miles away", for example:

> I can see the building from a mile away.
>
> I can score a goal from 50 yards.

In the context of your sentence, however, it doesn't really work as it still sounds like you mean *any time after*, so the same advice above applies.

Answer (score 0):

No. **'From ahead of'** isn't used in this way. You can't be ahead of a *play*: only a *performance* of it. Your car can be ahead of another car. They can be ahead of you.

> Rehearsals should start . . .
>
> or
>
> You should start rehearsing . . .
>
> . . . ten days ahead of the first performance.

'**From**' is not needed. More than one rehearsal IS!

> You should start rehearsals ten days before the first performance of the play.

Or

> The play will need ten days' rehearsals.

But 'We will be rehearsing **from** Jan 5th.'

> You should turn the indicators on one mile before the hospital.

If you are ahead of the hospital the hospital is following you!